# Identifier 'APEX_JSON.PARSE' must be declared in oracle 11.2.0

Tags: json, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I want to parse JSON in ***Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production***. But below error reported:

```
ORA-06550: line 4, column 5:
PLS-00201: identifier 'APEX_JSON.PARSE' must be declared
```

Here is my sample code:

```
DECLARE
    s varchar2(32767) := '{ "a": 1, "b": ["hello", "world"]}';
BEGIN
    apex_json.parse(s);
    sys.dbms_output.put_line('a is '||apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'a'));
END;
```

Does this version support this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the APEX version within your database, which I'm guessing may still be 4.x on your 11.2 instance.

```
SELECT VERSION_NO FROM APEX_RELEASE;
```

The apex_json package was introduced with 5.0
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_json.htm#AEAPI29635

Comment: appex version is 3.2.1. Thanks.