# How can I know if APEX_JSON is installed on my database?

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsql-package

I want to work with `json` data, in an Oracle database, so I tried the `apex_json` package.

I tried [this example](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_json.htm#AEAPI29636) from Oracle:

```
DECLARE
  s varchar2(32767) := '{ "a": 1, "b": ["hello", "world"]}';
BEGIN
  apex_json.parse(s);
  sys.dbms_output.put_line('a is '||apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'a'));
END;
```

But I get this error:

> APEX_JSON.parse must be declared.

How can I verify that `APEX_JSON` is installed on my db_server? 
Is there anything I need to do to activate it?

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45912298/7998591) ,you are probably using an older APEX version. Also, what's your Oracle database version? There are other functions like [JSON_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions093.htm) in 12c+ for parsing / extracting JSON elements

Comment: Version is 12.1.0.1.0

Answer (score 1):

1. Login as sysdba
2. Execute the script below:

   `select comp_name, version, status from dba_registry where comp_id='APEX';`

   It shows all details.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider upgrading Oracle to 12.1.0.2 or higher, where `JSON_VALUE` is available.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  s varchar2(32767) := '{ "a": 1, "b": ["hello", "world"]}';
  l_a INT;
BEGIN
  l_a := json_value(s,'$.a');
  dbms_output.put_line('a is '||l_a);
END;
/

a is 1


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not my desision to update the server. Is there no alternative when you are stuck with an old version?

Comment: There is at least one alternative; it is called "DIY" (Do It Yourself, manually).